# How to ensure users are always routed to the step they belong on in a multi-page form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 to build a series of forms (or steps) which must be filled out in order. I want to ensure the user is always directed to the correct "step" on every page load.

## Example #1

> I have a job application which is spread into 5 sections, with each
>   section being it's own page/form. The user comes to my site and fills
>   out pages 1 and 2, but then logs out. Later that week they come back
>   and log in. I want them to be automatically directed to page 3 of the
>   application.

My plan is to store the state (what page they belong on) in the database and then reference that when deciding where to route the user. I'm just not sure what the "Laravel way" of achieving this is. Where would I put this check to ensure the user belongs on the page?

## Example #2

> Same 5 page job application and the user has filled out pages 1 and 2.
>   We're using pretty basic URIs and the user assumes that if he's
>   currently on `site.com/formpage/2`, he can probably go to
>   `site.com/formpage/4` to skip ahead. When the user does this, the site
>   recognizes that the user "belongs" on page 3, and routes them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed you'll be having a route for that scenario such as

- `/form/1`
- `/form/2`
- `/form/3`

Basically `/form/{step}`.

So, whichever controller is responsible for this request should be the one validating the user is on the right step. If you're saving the state (the step on which the user should be redirected to), you can just compare whether the `$step` variable from the request matches the one you stored. If it doesn't, just redirect to appropriate one.

Pseudo-code:

```
public function foo($step)
{
    // get the step stored in the database, I'll just hard-code it
    $stepFromDatabase = 3;

    if ($stepFromDatabase != $step) {
        return redirect("/form/{$stepFromDatabase}");
    }

    // otherwise step is okay, so just display the form
    return view('bar');
}
```

Hope that helps.